# UIScrollView in Interface Builder not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

So I'm trying to put an image in my UI, and I've tried setting the content size.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    //[super viewDidLoad];
    _trendingImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trending.png"];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(2000, 2000)];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
    NSLog(@"VIEW WILL APPEAR BEING CALLED");
    self.rateView.notSelectedStar =[UIImage imageNamed:@"star-off.png"];
    self.rateView.fullSelectedStar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star-on.png"];
    self.rateView.rating = self.rating;
    self.rateView.editable = YES;
    self.rateView.maxRating = 5;
    self.rateView.delegate = self;
    _pageTitleLabel.text = _pageTitle;
    //_pageScoreLabel.text = _pageScore;
    _trendingImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trending.png"];
    _restaurantImageView.image = _restaurantImage;
    _descriptionView.text = _description;
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(2000,2000)];
}
```

The scrollView var is connected to a scroll view in the interface builder. This scroll view is inside another view, and it has subviews.

Why is this not scrolling?

This is the scrollView-

```
SCROLL VIEW : <UIScrollView: 0xac73010; frame = (0 -108; 320 676); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xac73bd0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xac731e0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

Comment: did you set scrollView's delegate?

Comment: oh I haven't set the delegate - how do I do that?

Comment: Setting the delegate has nothing to do with your problem. Did you log self.scrollView to make sure it's not nil?

Comment: yeah- I've put in the output in the question

Comment: You should post your project online, I will solve it for you.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058851/uiscrollview-delegate-methods-not-calling-properly/19195156#19195156

Comment: Make sure that the scrollingEnabled and userInteractionEnabled boxes are checked in IB. Other than that, setting the contentSize to something bigger than the scroll view's frame is all you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this lines in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
   self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2000, 2000)];
   [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
   [self.scrollView setClipsToBounds:YES];
   self.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

Also make sure that you conform to `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` in your .h file. Finally there is no need to set contentsize to both `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`. Leave it only in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: The delegate has nothing to do with getting the scroll view to scroll.

Comment: wait - so do I need to implement all this? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html

Comment: He already has a scroll view that he added in IB. Why would he create a new one? Also, if you make the frame the same size as the contentView it won't scroll.

Comment: rdelmar - do you have any ideas as to what the problem might be?

Comment: @praks5432, you might want to for other purposes, but you don't need to implement the delegate protocol to make a scroll view scroll.

Comment: If you do no not implement the delegate protocol and you use scrollView delegate methods, you will get a warning.

Comment: ok...so I added 

@interface BasicCardViewController : UIViewController<TooviaRateViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> - is that all I need?

Comment: also, Nikos - I've already added a scroll view in interface builder - why am I allocing a new one? Instead of allocing that, I tried the other three lines - still no dice

Comment: Your scrollview as set in IB has this frame: frame = (0 -108; 320 676); y parameter is unusual. Post a screenshot from your xib file

Comment: er..so it *looks* ok in interface builder

Comment: are you using autolayout and ios 7?

Comment: yeah I am - I saw that, that might interfere, so I unchecked it - same problem

Comment: wait - I just tried again - that totally fixed it - but what if I want it to scroll even when I turn it sideways?

Comment: If you have your autoresizing masks correct, landscape mode shouldn't be an issue